# CSS: How can I make a percentage bar in the background of a td in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make an order book widget. I am imitating [this example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/orderbook-forked-kh5xz?file=/src/index.css) where it has a `span` in `td` with `position: relative` and a `percent` `div` with its 'position`set to`absolute` and then it dynamically setting the width accordingly.

the code is like this

```css
td span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

table.Asks .percent {
  background-color: #fae9f1;
  z-index: 0;
}

table.Bids .percent {
  background-color: #f1f9e8;
}

td .percent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

So I was trying to do the same. [Here is a live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-morning-cn8pz?file=/src/styles.css) of what I did. The problem is it seems that all of the bars appear vertically instead of horizontally. I cannot figure out what went wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `td` is missing `position: relative;` so the absolute positioned element is not positioned relative to it

```
table .price {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}
```

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-keldysh-wj3jd?file=/src/styles.css